# How is the EJB Implementation getting hooked up in here?

Tags: spring, ejb-3.0

```
package com.apress.springrecipes.post;
import javax.ejb.Remote;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
@Stateless
@Remote( { PostageService.class })
public class PostageServiceBean implements PostageService {
    public double calculatePostage(String country, double weight) {
    return 1.0;
}
}
```

---

```
     jndi-name="PostageServiceBeanRemote">
        <jee:environment>
            java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.openejb.client.RemoteInitialContextFactory
            java.naming.provider.url=ejbd://127.0.0.1:4201
        </jee:environment>
    </jee:jndi-lookup>


    <bean id="frontDesk"
          class="com.apress.springrecipes.post.FrontDeskImpl">
        <property name="postageService" ref="postageService"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: I took more time formating then you did copy and pasting.  Please add some words explaining your code fragment, and give us a better code sample.

Comment: this question makes little sense, explain what it is you are after, otherwise this will be closed.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Spring only allows you to consume EJBs, which can be obtained from application server context. However, you cannot publish EJB beans with Spring: you need to use the facilities, provided by concrete application server for that (also depends on whether you want to use EJB 2 or EJB 3).

Have a look also at [EJB3 with Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950070/ejb3-with-spring).